# How can I find the appropriate hex code for this color?

Tags: css, hex, photoshop

I'll break down my issue for you:

Color #7fe5b2 shows up exactly the way I want it to in Photoshop. Exported .png files load wonderfully onto my site. It's perfect.

However, when plugging this hex code into css it becomes dithered and faint--it's green still, it's just not the same colour I was working with.

I've searched high and low for a possible answer, and I actually came up with a bit of a solution but it's still off. By taking screen shots the colour -- I get "3ce6a2", which is actually a lot closer, but it's still a little off -- I'm thinking there has to be a solution to this, and I would really appreciate your help. Hopefully it's a stupid question, with an easy answer, and if it is I really did spend ages looking for an answer and couldn't find one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Colors look different in browser and photoshop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699367/colors-look-different-in-browser-and-photoshop)

Comment: I suspect this has to do with color settings. Photoshop is advanced enough that it distinguishes between colors on-screen and colors on print out. This is kept in its color profile or color settings. CSS does not have such a concept, so the colors there are exactly what you get. I think you should be able to setup multiple color profiles - say, one for printing photos, one for on-screen webdesigns. You an then choose the unfancied profile for on-screen website work.

Comment: Do the CSS and PNG colors mis-match in all browsers or ONLY IN IE?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is Photoshop's color management. Try disabling color management in Photoshop, set your Working space RGB to Monitor RGB, and set the Color management RGB to off. Then repick your color in Photoshop (it will slightly change). Here is a more detailed explanation:
http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/

Answer (score 0):

Information regarding this color #7fe5b2 is following

1. RGB value is (127,229,178)
2. CMYK value is (0.45, 0.00, 0.22, 0.10)

I hope this will help